# How to hide element based on html attribute

Tags: html, css, hide

I want to hide the following element where the title is `View all posts`:

**I wrote the following code but it is not working:**

```css
[title='View all posts']{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/author/frank/" title="View all posts">
    <span>View all posts</span>
</a>
```

What is the correct CSS to hide element based on the title attribute?

Comment: your code is functional when I ran it, maybe check if there is something else overriding the styles you're trying to apply

Comment: You are right. `!important` was missing. As soon as I added, it worked.

Comment: "*`!important` was missing*" - I'd argue that using `!important` (anywhere) in your CSS was the real source of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your given CSS code you haven't added selector :

`a[title='View all posts']`

And also inspect your element by developer tools to see any other styles overriding this or making any conflicts.

Comment: `!important` was missing from my code due to which it was not working.